# Update folder contents

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created an application that gets the contents of a folder and lists them in a listview, I was wondering what is the best way to update that every 'X' seconds?

Previously I had a "Refresh" button in the GUI, however I want to move away from that and have an automatic refresh.

I have used this, however I understand that the `Sleep()` will cause the application to stop entirely until the timer is up:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RefreshQueue();
    label1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
    while (i > 1)
    {
        RefreshQueue();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

And also:

```
public void Update()
{
    RefreshQueue();
}
```

The `RefreshQueue()` clears the current listbox and calls `PrintQueue()`:

```
public void PrintQueue()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryLocation);
    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTime))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(directoryLocation + fi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code that you have already tried?

Comment: Use a timer, perhaps? Or a FileSystemWatcher? For better answers, you should describe what you already have implemented and where you got stuck. Also, the used technology (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, ...) matters.

Comment: I have tried to use Update() methods, as well as just a While(i = 1) loop. I have been trying to use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) to wait 1 second. This is while using forms.

Comment: Did you have a look at [System.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: The problem with WinForms and executing any waiting/asynchronous code within the code behind is that it executes in the same thread as the UI.  This means that if you want to periodically update the UI, you have to use a means to update the data in the background and then signal to the UI it needs to update itself from the newly retrieved data. In this case, you need a timer executing in the background that simply tells to the UI to update the folder contents from the .Net file system APIs.

Comment: FYI, I gave you hints above rather than a full solution, because I've not written in WinForms in nearly 6 years and there are likely better approaches than I can give. Regardless, there are many ways to solve this problem.  Maybe the simplest in your case is to use a `BackgroundWorker` object, and every 5-10 seconds have it reload the folder data.

Comment: For BackgroundWorker with a WinForms app, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation

Comment: Thank you RLH, I have done a little more experimenting and a background task that only updates when there is a change in the folder or to the files seems to be the best way to go.